# image of search icon not visible inside search box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, search, icons

I am not able to figure out why the image of search icon does not appear inside the search box when using the image after downloading but appears when directly using the link.Any suggestions?The image is this: http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/pretty_search_forms/images/search.png

```
<div  class="bar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">  
            <a href="main.php">XYZ</a>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-xs-5 right-inner-addon has-feedback">
               <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                 <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                 <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess4"></label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess4" placeholder="Search">     
                 </div>
               </form>             
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

.right-inner-addon {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left:30px;

}
.right-inner-addon input {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    background-image: url('images/search.png');
    background-position: 370px -10px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.form-control{
    min-width: 400px; 
    max-width: 400px; 
    min-height: 29px;
    top: 7px;
    position: fixed;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `background-position` property value to something like  `365px 5px`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mj5a8/) - (Not sure where you want it positioned - but now it's visible at least)

```
.right-inner-addon input {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    background-image: url('http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/pretty_search_forms/images/search.png');
    background-position: 365px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Actually I do not want to use the link provided in background-image url .. rather use that same image after downloading it and providin the relative location of the image ..but when I do that the image does not appear

Comment: @user3452721 It must be the path then. Where is the image in your directory? It's worth noting that partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document

Comment: @user3452721 You could try `url('../images/search.png')` .. or `url('/images/search.png')`.

Comment: the problem was in background position as suggested by you and not in relative location..thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to specify px in positioining. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mP4jc/).

CSS:

```
.right-inner-addon input {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    background: url('http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/pretty_search_forms/images/search.png') no-repeat right center;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok . you should put this in the line of the search icon .

```
background-image: url('../images/search.png');
```

please be attention  to the directory 
 you do that if your photo is in your local machine 
don't forget this ok (../ before your directory )

Answer (score 0):

if your image is on line in this like you put this is your new code :

background: url('http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/pretty_search_forms/images/search.png') no-repeat right center;

but if you have a images file in your local pc you shpuld put this code :

```
background-image: url('../images/search.png');
```